# MySQL statement to get data from 'user' table and last message from 'chat' table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a 'users' table for general information of every user (primary key is 'user_id') and a table 'chat' to store messages (primary key is 'msg_id') that have 'incoming_msg_id' (which eventually corresponds with 'users.user_id') and 'outgoing_msg_id' (which eventually corresponds with 'users.user_id').
'chat.read_at' is 'null' as long as the message is not read but is a date/time field.

I wish to list all users and their corresponding last message, if there is any.

With the following statement I have errors as I get also messages that are not from or to the corresponding user.

I am pretty new to SQL and trying to dig my way through it and did several attempts to do it with (INNER) JOIN but never got so far as with this statement:

```
    SELECT user_id, username, image, status, active,
    CASE WHEN status IN ("Active Now") THEN true ELSE false END AS isonline,
    (SELECT msg 
    FROM chat
    WHERE
    (incoming_msg_id = users.user_id) OR
    (outgoing_msg_id = users.user_id)
    ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS last_msg,

    (SELECT msg_id
    FROM chat
    WHERE
    (incoming_msg_id = users.user_id) OR
    (outgoing_msg_id = users.user_id)
    ORDER BY msg_id DESC LIMIT 1 ) AS last_msg_id,

    (SELECT outgoing_msg_id
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS outgoing_msg_id,

    (SELECT incoming_msg_id
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS incoming_msg_id,

    (SELECT created_at
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS last_interaction, 

    (SELECT IF(read_at = null, false, true)
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS has_unread_msg,

    (SELECT read_at
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS read_at,

    (SELECT IF(user_id = incoming_msg_id, true, false) AS isme
    FROM chat
    WHERE msg_id = last_msg_id
    ) AS self 

    FROM users
    WHERE
    (NOT user_id = ?) AND 
    (users.username LIKE ?)
    ORDER BY active DESC, status ASC, has_unread_msg DESC, last_interaction DESC
```

My code after the first comment with the exact same result (showing messages that do not belong to me and some of the other users listed:

```
   WITH 
   cte1 AS (
      SELECT *, incoming_msg_id as user_id FROM chat
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *, outgoing_msg_id FROM chat
      ),
   cte2 AS (
      SELECT *, IF(ISNULL(read_at), true, false) AS has_unread_msg, msg AS last_msg, IF(user_id = incoming_msg_id, true, false) AS self, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
      FROM cte1
      )
   SELECT *, IF(status = "Active now", true, false) AS isonline
   FROM users
   JOIN cte2 USING (user_id)
   WHERE rn = 1
```

Create and inserts of the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat` (
  `msg_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `incoming_msg_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `outgoing_msg_id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `read_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


INSERT INTO `chat` (`msg_id`, `incoming_msg_id`, `outgoing_msg_id`, `msg`, `read_at`, `created_at`) VALUES
(3, 1, 5, 'no way', '2022-10-23 17:53:13', '2022-10-23 17:53:13'),
(4, 1, 5, 'I am sitting here and nothing happens!', '2022-10-23 17:53:13', '2022-10-23 17:53:13'),
(5, 1, 5, 'Still sitting here...', '2022-10-23 17:53:13', '2022-10-23 17:53:13'),
(9, 5, 1, 'Hi there', '2022-10-23 16:13:25', '2022-10-23 16:13:25'),
...
(45, 5, 25, 'Hey there. How is ya doing??', '2022-10-22 08:16:18', '2022-10-22 08:16:18'),
(46, 3, 25, 'hello there! Are you available?', '2022-10-23 18:16:08', '2022-10-23 18:16:08'),
(47, 3, 25, 'Something?', '2022-10-23 18:16:08', '2022-10-23 18:16:08'),
(48, 1, 25, 'hi!', '2022-10-24 11:45:13', '2022-10-24 11:45:13'),
(49, 1, 25, 'hi!', '2022-10-24 11:45:13', '2022-10-24 11:45:13'),
...
(63, 25, 5, 'nothing special here!', '2022-10-23 21:29:04', '2022-10-23 21:29:04'),
(64, 5, 25, 'What if we meet next week?', '2022-10-22 08:16:18', '2022-10-22 08:16:18'),
(65, 5, 25, 'What if we meet next week?', '2022-10-22 08:16:18', '2022-10-22 08:16:18'),
...
(365, 2, 5, 'sechs', NULL, '2022-10-21 20:49:09'),
(366, 2, 5, 'sieben', NULL, '2022-10-21 20:49:10'),
(367, 2, 5, 'acht', NULL, '2022-10-21 20:50:18'),
(368, 2, 5, 'neun', NULL, '2022-10-21 20:50:19'),
```

msg_id is primary and incremental

This is the users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET armscii8 NOT NULL,
  ...
  `image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  ...
  `active` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `status` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Not active',
  `last_chat_notification_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

[image: screenshot of output]

The first users are correct (talking to me as I am logged in with the user_id 25)
But from the 6th user on it shows messages that are not between us.

The list shows every existing user but only the last message between them and the currently logged in user (or non if not applicable).
The current user should also be excluded from the list.

Comment: *I wish to list all users and their corresponding last message, if there is any.* Regardless of the direction and `read_at` value?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: I don’t know what is meant by ‚direction‘ but every user should there only be once and should only have one last message (ingoing or outgoing) and read_at has the information if the message has already been read. I want all, regardless of the status of read_at

Comment: *I don’t know what is meant by ‚direction‘* I mean do you need in the rows which are only sent by user, or received by user, or the rows where the user takes part in any role.

Comment: PS. What is precise MySQl version? show output for `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes, both rows should be there. But in the moment I have also messages from other users in there. I guess in the case there is none.
Maria DB 10.5.16

Comment: Output of SELECT VERSION(): 10.5.16-MariaDB-1:10.5.16+maria~focal-log

Comment: Your DBMS version allows to enumerate rows within the group in CTE using ROW_NUMBER() and select the most recent row per user in outer query. A bunch of subqueries not needed.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with PHP? To me, this looks like a raw MySQL problem?

Comment: I think that providing the sample data (5-7 rows) with desired output for it may help. As CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: I guess my original question is incomplete as this is a list the presents to every logged in user different. It should show the last message between the listed users and the logged in user (or none if not applicable). I edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

Schematically:

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, user_from as user_id FROM messages
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, user_to FROM messages
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
)
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN cte2 USING (user_id)
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Great, thanks! So much tidier. But it still has the same result. I extended the code with the required fields and it has the exact same result in showing messages that do not belong to me and my user_id (with the users listed).

Comment: I don't get it. When I put the WHERE clause within cte2 it only shows the users that have interacted with me. When I put it in the end it does not show any user.
Why is there the UNION ALL in cte1 as every column definitely has incoming_msg_id and outgoing_message_id?

Comment: @marcushorndt Create a fiddle with your issue and provide the link.

Comment: @marcushorndt Use https://dbfiddle.uk/ *it does not let me use the WITH statement* I think that you forget to specify correct DBMS version.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Ne8ucIys

Comment: I do not know how to get the variable into the fiddle which notices "who I am" aka with which user_id I am logged in. Because this is the point: One should only see the interaction that took place between every user and the user_id currently logged in. So in case my user_id is '25' I should see every user listed but only the last messages of every user with myself. User with no interaction so far just do not have a "last message".
And I should not see myself listed.

Comment: See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8-DyvNJZ). It shows my query and its step-by-step action. CTE1 shows how the data is converted to groups "where the user takes part in any direction", the data is sorted for these groups to be visual. CTE2 shows this rowset enumeration. And final query selects the rows which are "last for each user". If you need  the same for only one definite user then you must add according conditions into CTE1 (select only those rows where this user takes part in) and into outer query (remove self). See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Idp_L64K).

Comment: Super explanation and detailed fiddle...thanks so much! For extracting the messages it is great working. But I still need every user listed and if there is no common message the 'msg_id' and 'msg' would than be empty as in the original question asked.
I can't see / do not understand how to change your setup with that requirement.

Comment: I extended it again with the columns needed by the calling PHP-script, put the query back in my environment and it does not pull the last messages but they are kind of randomly changing. I can see it in the fiddle, too. There is actually one message with rn = 8 (msg_id = 11) but displayed in the end is the message with msg_id = 10
Don't know why it is not working with created _at but it is more correct with msg_id as ORDER BY

Answer (score 0):

Introduced to more advanced SQL concepts and guided through various steps of data extraction by @Akina I came to the following solution to the question:

```
WITH
cte1 AS (
    SELECT *, incoming_msg_id AS user_id FROM chat
    WHERE @user_id IN (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, outgoing_msg_id FROM chat
    WHERE @user_id IN (incoming_msg_id, outgoing_msg_id)
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY msg_id DESC) rn
    FROM cte1
),
cte3 AS (
    SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE user_id <> @user_id AND rn = 1
)
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN cte3 USING (user_id);
```

This solution selects the last chat messages if there is any but nevertheless displays all existing users.